# Why does responses.get sometimes not get the whole html page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, response

In crawling [this page](https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?release_date=2017-01-01,2017-12-31&sort=num_votes,desc&start=51) I would like to extract movies' ratings (PG, PG-13, etc.) Everything seems to be OK, except for the movie named "Reis".

[image]

There is a certificate for that (12) but it appears Responses.get has not downloaded that part's HTML code (beautifulsoup does not find anything, and I also took a look at response.text.) I had a similar issue with urllib.request in some cases too. The response was successful in both cases (it returns 200). What is the best way to deal with issue?

This is my code:

```
from requests import get 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



def movie_catalog_pages(base_url):
    response = None
    try:
        response = get(base_url)
    except:
        print("Not loaded "+ base_url)

    return response

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?release_date=2017-01-01,2017-12-31&sort=num_votes,desc&start=101'
response = movie_catalog_pages(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


movies = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-advanced')

for movie in movies:

    # Movie number
    try:
        temp = movie.h3.span.text
    except:
        temp = None

    if (temp == None):
        i = (np.NaN)
    else:
        i = (int(temp.replace('.','').replace(',','')))

    # movie certificate
    try:
        temp = movie.p.find('span', class_="certificate").text
    except:
        temp = None
        print('Error================================', i)

    if (temp == None):
        pass
    else:
        print(i,temp)
```

Comment: I don't see any such "12" when I visit the page.

Comment: Same experience for me as @BrenBarn, no `12` on the page for that film

Comment: @BrenBarn look a the picture in the question, I have highlighted the "12"

Comment: @Mr.Who: I see your picture.  What I'm saying is that when *I* visit the page, *I* don't see a 12, so it's not as simple as just saying "the content is on the page".  The page content may vary depending on the client somehow (e.g., if you have some browser extensions enabled, or depending on the user agent or source IP).

Comment: That might be a region thing that imdb does because for us there is no "12"

Comment: @BrenBarn, Yup you are right, I change my IP address and it gone

Comment: @BrenBarn I use a cloud service to crawl the page, that caused the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank to the comments I noticed that I problem caused by my own IP address and the computer that I do the crawling.